# Explicit instantiation declaration with extern

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am reading 14.7.2 in C++ Standard draft n3485 and it says:

> 2 The syntax for explicit instantiation is:
>   explicit-instantiation:
>   `extern`*opt* template declaration
>
> There are two forms of explicit instantiation: an explicit instantiation definition and an explicit instantiation declaration. **An explicit instantiation declaration begins with the `extern` keyword.**

Seeing that a template declaration and definition is always put in a header, I have never seen a declaration with `extern` on a template.  What exactly does that bolded sentence mean?

Also why would an instantiation care about `extern`?

Comment: "_Also why would an instantiation care about extern?_" Because that's the syntax used for an explicit instantiation declaration. Why would the compiler ignore valid syntax that changes the meaning of a decaration? Like `extern int i;` it says "this is a declaration, not a definition, there will be a definition somewhere in the program"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It tells the compiler not to instantiate that template in this TU.

Note that it should be instantiated in one TU (without the `extern` bit), if you want your code to actually link.